# How to use click in table cell except click on a select box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

have a table which containing some images and some select boxes .I want to highlight row whenever user click on that row(means any td) except select boxes and images

Now i am using this,

```
$("selector").live("click",function() {
    $(this)
        .parents("tr:first")
        .toggleClass("diffColor")
    ;
});
```

But it is applying the class if i click on select box or image.But i dont need when i click on select box or any other images.

see here

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle

Comment: ok wait 2min.I will provide

Comment: are you missing a # or . in your $('selector')  ?

Comment: just i am saing selector.I put in my code

Comment: @ Dolours see here http://jsfiddle.net/YJQvZ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".selector").on("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target === this) $(this).parent("tr:first").toggleClass("diffColor");
});
```

Assumming the fact that `.selector` is the class name for all the `td`

Here, `this` means the element in the current scope, which is always the `td` clicked here.

and `e.target` means the element actually clicked, which can be `td` or `checkbox` or anything inside the `td`.

So, in case the element actually clicked is not the `td` in the current scope, `e.target === this` return false and nothing happens (no click event is fired) and vice-versa.

Comment: it is working for me.thank u so much.I am working from past 2 hrs

Comment: This issue is quite common for the nested `elements` and this is the simple solution for it.

Comment: What would happen if there was a nested element other than a `select` or an `img` though? The `toggleClass` wouldn't occur..

Comment: Actually this one's better than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to `toggleClass` when clicking on a `td` which contains an `<img>` or `<select>` you can do the following:

```
$('selector').live('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).has('select, img').length) {
      $(this).parents('tr:first').toggleClass('diffColor');
    }
});
```

#### [Here's your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQvZ/7/)

Answer (score 2):

I have solution with checking if the TD contains image or select box.

```
$("#tableId td").on("click",function() {  
     var ths=$(this);    
     if((ths.has("select").length ? false : true)&&(ths.has("img").length ? false : true)){
         $(this).parent().toggleClass("diffColor");
     }
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQvZ/13/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
$("td").live("click",function() {
$(this)
    .parents("tr:first")
    .toggleClass("diffColor")
;
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xvwRW/)

Comment: check if the specific td contains any img or select tags if present dn't toggle class else add the same.

Answer (score 0):

will this be ok for you? just add class "change" to td.

```
$("#tableId td.change").on("click",function() {
        $(this)
            .parents("tr:first")
            .toggleClass("diffColor")
        ;
    });


<table id="tableId" border="1">
     <thead>
        <th></th>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        <th>Third</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        <td><input type="checkbox"/></td>
        <td class="change">FirstTableColumn1</td>
        <td class="change">FirstTableColumn2</td>
        <td><select>
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
            <option>CCC</option>
            <option>DDD</option>
            </select></td>

     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your events are bubbling up.

you can add an event.stopPropagation for the click events on the children to prevent this.

so for any input and select elements add the following to prevent propagation. if you already have event handlers for the clicks, add stopPropagation to the beginning of your functions.

```
$("#tableId").find("input, select")
             .click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
```